# How can I add to the end of the string that already exists in input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now, If I hit the button, it clears all in the input field, and it automatically inputs "@marry" to it.
But, I don't want it to be cleared:(

What if I want to add "@marry" to the end of the strings that already exists in the input field?

How can I customize my javascript part?

**Input field**

```
<textarea class="box text_area" cols="10" id="input" name="comment[body]"></textarea>
```

**button**

```
<a href="#topic" id="username" value="@marry”><span class='btn'>reply</span></a>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#username', function()  {
    $(".box#input").val($(this).attr('value'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)'s answer is good and you should read it. Here is an alternative solution that does not use jQuery:

I assume that both these elements are a part of a form. Let's say for instance the form has an ID of `"post"`. We can access it using `document.forms` and then its fields as such:

```
 var input = document.forms.post["comment[body]"];
```

Now, we can add to its value whenever the button is clicked. First select `username` with getElementById or querySelector and then add the event:

```
username.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
     input.value += ev.target.value;
});
```

Or with jQuery (this also delegates if the element is not in the DOM yet):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#username', function()  {
    input.value += this.value;
});
```

It might be desirable to append an extra space between the current text and the username.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I'm doing this `var input = $(".box#input");` and 'input.value += this.value;' but it clears all and inputs `@marry` :( why it won't add...

Comment: You need to do `input = $(...).get(0)` to get the dom element

Comment: You need to extract the DOM element from the jQuery selection set if you don't want to use querySelector.

Answer (score 4):

`val()` has a callback with the arguments `index` and `value`, you can use that to easily add something to the value.

```
$(".box#input").val(function(_, val) {
    return this.value + 'some extra string';
});
```

---

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#username', function()  {
    var self = this;

    $(".box#input").val(function(_, val) {
        return val + self.value;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! can't you do it in one line? something like '$(".box#input").val($(this)+ $(".box#input").val($(this).attr('value'));'

Comment: I'm talking about something like this kind of thing `result = result + "some strings here"`

Comment: @MKK you can do that if you use vanilla JavaScript rather than jQuery.

Comment: @MKK - Sure you can, `this.value = this.value + 'something'`, but in your example you're not telling us what `this` is? If you think it's the element, it won't be unless you use a callback or it's otherwise in the rigth scope etc.

Comment: @adeneo I did updated my question. Does it help you understanding what I'm trying to ask?

Comment: @adeneo basically I want to let user click on someone's user name, and he might click on the other user's name in a row. In that case, the input field should be filled with `@marry @John '. Does this make sense?

Comment: First, you should have a selector on the form, once you do - (let's call it `form` you can do: `form["comment[body]"]).value += "@marry";`

Comment: @adeneo I tried your 2nd answer but it still clears all inside of input field and inputs '@marry':(

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Would you mind to post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

append @marry at the end of text area. you can use bellow code its working fine.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#username', function () {
    var txtvalue = $(".box#input").val();
    $(".box#input").val(txtvalue + $(this).attr('value'));
});
```

see jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/F6mkh/1/